# Google Translate on WordPress(.com)

Tags: wordpress, google-translate

Since scripts are not allowed on WordPress(.com) blogs, I was wondering whether there is a way to get the following [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/translate_tools?hl=en&layout=1&eotf=1) code to work on a WordPress (.com) blog via the Text widget? Thanks in advance.

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div><script>
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({
    pageLanguage: 'en'
  }, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script><script src="http://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't run most JS on wordpress.com, but there seems to be a workaround to use Google Translate: http://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/translation-widget?replies=20

Answer (score 0):

You're making it too complicated -- you can just use html.  Color coded explanation with a little story here:

http://conradcook.wordpress.com/2012/07/21/machine-translation-fail/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. [By the way, this answer was just flagged as spam. You should disclose that this is *your* blog and besides that include the relevant parts in the answer itself.]